# MySQL LINQ to SQL Provider Visual Studio 2012

Tags: mysql, linq, visual-studio

I would like to use the Visual Studio 2012 LINQ to SQL Classes feature.  I installed the MySQL Connector/Net version 6.6.4. In VS I was able to add a connection to the MySQL database.  I then added a new item, "Linq to SQL Classes".  It opened the workspace.  I dragged the MySQL table to the workspace and received the following error: "The selected object(s) use an unsupported data provider".  In my connection it states that the following provider is being used, ".NET Framework Data Provider for MySQL.

I use the same procedure with MSSQL and it works perfect every time.

It is correct that the Oracle/MySQL Connector/Net version 6.6.4 (which is the latest) does not support VS 2012 LINQ to SQL Classes?  Note that I don't want to use LINQ to Entity.

Thanks!  Todd

Comment: take a look at this: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft does not provide "Linq to SQL" for non-Microsoft RDBMS. But others do. Check out 
[devart](http://www.devart.com/linqconnect/) (Ukraine) and  [Mindspeed](http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/LightSpeed/default.aspx) (New Zealand).
Neither is free, but both have  free versions for up to 8 or 10 entity types (not 8 tables!) respectively.